# random color per div group css

Tags: css

Im trying to give each group a random color. 
This is the site I'm working on. The courses are not hard-coded but fetched from our db.

http://193.191.177.139/agenda.html

This is what I've tried, because I have no idea how to do the random colors thing, but I can't even get this working:

```
.vis-foreground .vis-group .vis-item .vis-item-overflow :nth-child(even) { background: blue;}

.vis-foreground .vis-group .vis-item .vis-item-overflow :nth-child(odd) { background: red;}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to start with the random color thing?

Comment: What is `random colors thing`?

Comment: To give each group's items a random color :) so that it is more clear which assignments are part of a course

Answer (score 0):

YOu shouldnt give space between :nth-child and the selector.

The code should be something like this.

```
.vis-foreground .vis-group .vis-item .vis-item-overflow:nth-child(even) { background: blue;}
```

or

Based on the selector you want to target

```
.vis-foreground .vis-group .vis-item:nth-child(even) { background: blue;}
```